# React native Array.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm a junior in js development so this might be a silly question, so apologies.

I'm using firebase in my app to store my strings, I call it once when the app is loaded and keep it in memory for faster access.

Then I use strings.find to find a specific string in the array. All work find when running on iOS, but when running on Android I keep getting this weird error

```
TypeError: Undefined is not a function (evaluting 'this.strings.find...
```

Here's my data schema

`{'strings': [{'name':'something', 'value':'something'} ... ]`

And here's my code

`getString(name) {
    return this.strings.find(x => x.name == name).value
  }`

And this is where I define the object

```
init(onUpdated) {
    Promise.all([stringsDb.once('value'), multiLang.once('value')])
      .then(([stringsSnapshot, multiLangSnapshot]) => {

        this.strings = stringsSnapshot.value
        this.multiLang = multiLangSnapshot.value

        onUpdated(true)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.stack)
        onUpdated(false)
      });
  }
```

Comment: Where are you setting `this.strings`?

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks! I edited the question

Comment: my guess is (because it's asynchronous) `this.strings` undefined before the promise is resolved and `this.strings` is assigned to. Call `getName` after `this.strings` is set or check to see if it's not undefined before performing `find`.

Comment: I thought that, so I printed this.strings to the console, and it is defined already (I use callbacks to only call the find after the strings is already defined)

Answer (score 3):

This probably happens because the `this.strings` is not an array. you need to debug it and see if its actually an array or not, my guess is it returns an object, if so then you need to use a reducer or perhaps `Object.values` or something to convert to an array.

p.s you should use the `===` operator when comparing the strings

Comment: Thank you!! That's was exactly it. Turns out firebase for Android doesn't return the same object as for iOS, so I'll have to convert it to arrive before using